# jQuery ajax not returning error or success or always

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm going crazy here... no matter what I do, I don't get ANY console.log or alert, just this error: GET https://externalURL/?callback=jQuery111301768235498533206_1458134520045&_=1458134520046

This is my code, I have left in the commented lines so you can see what I have tried until now. I'm usign jQuery 1.11.1.

```
var dataa = {
    input: {
        id : "12",
        tripDate : "2016-02-01"
    }
};

jQuery.ajax({
  //method : "POST",
    type : "POST",
    url: "https://externalURL/",
    //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    //crossDomain: true,
    //data : JSON.stringify(dataa),     
    //data : dataa,     
    data : {input:{id:12,tripDate:"2016-02-01"}},       
    //data : {id:12,tripDate:"2016-02-01"},
    //processdata: true,
    /*error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('nem' + jqXHR)
    },*/
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            alert('Time out error.');
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            alert('Ajax request aborted.');
        } else {
            alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    },
    success : function(r) {
        console.log(r);
    }        
  })
 .done(function() {
    console.log( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
  });
```

Could this be because it's an external url? Would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: what is the actual error, normally on chrome you'll see GET http://localhost:8091/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED this part tells you why it failed

Comment: btw: If you want to send a json, you should use `contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'` and `data: JSON.stringify({whatever})`

Comment: the actual error in chrome console is as I mentioned above: GET https://externalURL//?callback=jQuery…309902066141186563_1458134097129&id=12&tripDate=2016-02-01&_=1458134097130 if I use jsonp. If I use json as dataType, I get: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://externalURL/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://dev.imok.ro' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `dataType: "jsonp"` to `dataType: "json"`.

This [Article](http://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/) was helpful when I went into the same issue once.

Comment: yeah and depending on if you want the values in data to be sent as POST values or call body, do not use or use stringify, respectively.

Comment: also, if you insist on using jsonp, does the function in the callback parameter exist and is it called?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out, that the external URL provided incorrect information for the dataa variable. Thanks everyone for the useful tips!